# Code start and end in specific time

Tags: php, date, dst

Hi guys i have a code that start and end in specific time, my code is work fine but i want to use this code in data that loop
for example i'll pot names in loop and i want for each one to start and end in specific time:

this is my code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$time = date('Y:m:d H:i:s');
$timestart = date('Y:m:d H:i:s'); //time start
$timeend = '2016:11:17 10:56:00'; //time end

if($time >= $timeend){
echo "time end";
}else{
    echo 'untel end time';
    }


$now = new DateTime();
$future_date = new DateTime($timeend);
$interval = $future_date->diff($now);
?>
```

and i want to know how to use it with loop data?

thanks.

Comment: you need cron to run a script at a set time

Comment: no cron isn't required

Comment: So are you running the script in a continuos loop checking the time over and over?

Comment: yes, i have data in my sql and i get it in php by loop and i want each one of it end in the time i chose

Comment: That is a horrible idea. Eventually you will either run out of resources or the script will fail. I highly recommend using cron so the file will be triggered at a specific time.

Comment: What does this have to do with NodaTime? You're using PHP... please only include genuinely related tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EV or Event extension or implement by loop. I prefer EV extension to this task

And create timer for example:

```
// Required create variable!
$w = new EvTimer($needWorkedSeconds, $repeatAfterSecond, function ($w) {
    echo "iteration = ", Ev::iteration(), PHP_EOL;
});

// Loop until Ev::stop() is called or all of watchers stop
Ev::run();
```

[More read here!](http://php.net/manual/en/ev.examples.php)

OR use event (but i prefer event to work with socket):

```
$base = new \EventBase();
$e = \Event::timer($base, function($n) use (&$e) {
    echo "$n seconds elapsed\n";
    if($isTimeEndNow)
    {
         $e->delTimer();
    }
}, $repeatAfterSecond);
$e->addTimer($repeatAfterSecond);
$base->loop();
```

[More read here!](http://php.net/manual/ru/event.addtimer.php)

Or you can try while, for example:

```
while(true)
{
    if($isTimeEndNow)
    {
         break;
    }
    sleep($repeatAfterSecond);
}
```

In example i use undeclareted variable:

```
$repeatAfterSecond - seconds to next iteration or next call
$isTimeEndNow - this is: time() > $endTimestamp
$needWorkedSeconds - this is seconds: time_start - time_end
```

**ATTENTIONAL!!! Be Careful!** I think you make mistake, if you want use MySQL and if you need die script in concrete time. Review your algorithm!!!